# Looking for a cordova plugin to prompt a user

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

i'm currently working on a cordova app, and i'm looking for this type of prompt on ios : 
[image]

I found the picture on this page : 
https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser
but I'm not sure it is only for the prompt i want, it also implements a sort of in app browser. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called an ActionSheet and a plugin can be found here: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet#2-screenshots

Disclaimer: I'm the plugin's author.

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect :-) 
Good luck in the development of the plugin!

Comment: How to use it in a single menu ? Because on the demo of your plugin there are the 3 separate functions

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood something on the readme ! By the way I'd like to thank you a lot not only for your answer but also for your plugin. Very usefull and easy to put in place :-)